# Can we perform the reverse of concatenation in a Python loop?

Tags: python, loops, operators, typeerror

I was messing around with word animation in [Python Sandbox](http://pythonsandbox.com/), and it told me that I cannot use the '-' operator to remove a character from a string. This seems completely illogical to me, as we can use the '+' operator to concatenate two strings. Here is my code:

```
from time import sleep
def animate(word):
  result = ""
  while result != word:
    for char in word:
      result += char
      print result
      sleep(1)
  else:
    for char in word:
      result -= char
      print result
      sleep(1)
animate("test")
```

This is what I expect as output (after the animation is complete):

```
t
te
tes
test
tes
te
t
```

This code works for lines 1-4, then throws this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for Sub: 'str' and 'str' on line 11
```

Why can't I subtract the characters as I added them?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround!

Here is the new, working code:

```
from time import sleep
def animate(word):
    result = ""
    d = {}
    key = 0
    rnge = len(word)-1
    while result != word:
    for char in word:
        result += char
        key += 1
        d[key] = result
        print result
        sleep(0.1)
    for x in range(rnge):
        print d[rnge-x]
        sleep(0.1)
animate("animation")
```

Essentially, as the first section of the animation progresses, I save each step as an entry in a previously empty dictionary, then use a simple for loop to iterate through the dictionary backwards. Neat!

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it, we can easily add any string to a string,

but if we want to subtract a string from a string, we have to know exactly what characters the strings ends with.

If it doesn't matter, you can just use a subscription like `string = string[:-1]` to remove the last character from the string.

If it does matter, use `remove()` to remove a specific part of the string (not necessarily from the end)

Comment: Strings are not lists, there is no `pop` in str.

Comment: Fixed it, I can't believe myself!